# Accessing to the first `.SD` in `dt[, .SD[.SD[<something else>], by = b], by = a]`

Tags: r, data.table

Let's consider the following data table

```
dt <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6), d = c(7,8,9))
```

I would like to subset `dt` once with `dt[, .SD[<something>], by = a]` and inside the subset `.SD`, I would like to invoke another subsetting as

```
dt[, .SD[.SD[<something else>], by = b], by = a]
```

But inside the second subsetting `<something else>`, I would like to access to the first `.SD` in `dt[, .SD[<something>], by = a]`.

Is this possible with the data.table syntax?

---

A typical application: Mean-square displacement calculations.
Consider a dataset, where you have particles identified with `AgentID` and their displacement over time, specified by `displacement` and `Time` variables.
For each `AgentID` and `Time`, you need to calculate `cumsum(displacement)` for all `t > Time` where.

e.g if

```
dt <- data.table(Time = c(1,2,3), AgentID = c(1), displacement = c(-2,4,-6))
```

then one would typically do

```
DT <- dt[, .(msd = cumsum(dt[Time >= .BY$Time & AgentID == .BY$AgentID]$displacement)), by = .(Time, AgentID)]
DT
   Time AgentID msd
1:    1       1  -2
2:    1       1   2
3:    1       1  -4
4:    2       1   4
5:    2       1  -2
6:    3       1  -6
```

Calling `dt` inside `dt` is not ideal for several reasons. Instead I want to subset twice; e.g `dt[.SD[.SD[<calculate msd>], by = Time], by = AgentID]`, but while inside of the inner-most `.SD`, I need to access the outer `.SD`.

Comment: Please clarify: (1) `Time > Time` is ambiguous, which is which? (2) Other than that it doesn't do yet what you want, your code is syntactically broken in at least three places (missing commas, misplaced `]`). (3) To better clarify what you think this should be doing, please include the expected results given this (still fictional) code? Perhaps we can propose an alternate solution.

Comment: @r2evans uhm ... I wasn't trying to write a syntatically correct code; that was just a pseudo-code trying explain what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: I get it. While pseudocode is not intended to be perfect, it should be unambiguous. What is `.SD_first[Time > Time]displacement` supposed to be? I don't know which `Time` is which, and I don't know if it might be `.SD_first[Time > Time, displacement]` or `.SD_first[Time > Time], displacement`, which are two different operations. Please add expected values for this notional code; whereas "a picture paints a 1000 words" in some contexts (not here, please :-), in programming I find that "explicit expected output given this input" is equally clarifying.

Comment: At least for your example, you may do a self-non equi join, and use `by = .EACHI` to do the desired calculation by each match in `i`: `dt[dt, on = .(AgentID, Time >= Time), .(msd = cumsum(displacement)), by = .EACHI]` gives the result shown in OP.

Comment: @Henrik thanks for the comment. Could you elaborate on what `self-non equi join` is ?

Comment: @Our The "self" refers to that `dt` is joined with itself (`dt[dt, on = .(AgentID, Time >= Time)`). For the latter part. well, please take you time to study the help text, and search. You _will_ find ;)